# Is a contract agreed to in an illegal way binding?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, oregon

Suppose I, an amateur radio operator, want to buy a car from another amateur radio operator. I send him a contract over ham radio, and he agrees to it. We have violated amateur radio regulations by using it for commercial purposes, but does this nullify the contract?

Comment: Can you expound on what you mean by sending a contract over the radio?  Was it digitally transmitted in a format that was, or could be, printed and signed?  Was the contract verbal?  Was the car advertised via amateur radio?  If not, how did you become aware the car was for sale?  Did you know the seller ahead of time?

Comment: @MichaelHall yes, let's say it was sent by radiofax. The signers knew each other previously and the buyer knew the car was for sale, they just signed the contract over radio.

Comment: What about a contract printed on paper that I have stolen? Apart from the problem that the shop I stole from could demand that I return all copies of those contracts printed on stolen paper back to them...

Comment: @gnasher, could the thief counter-sue for the rights to the created content on the paper?

Comment: I think the best analogy is a contract formed while the offeror and offeree are trespassing on a third party's property. I don't know of any law that would allow either party to void the contract on that basis.

Comment: People talk about buying/selling radio equipment on the air often enough to not be remarkable. What is different about a car in this case? The transmission in data mode of the actual contract? Is a private sale actually a commercial transaction?

Comment: @JonCuster there's a specific exemption for selling ham radio equipment.

Comment: @Someone - yes, but the intent of the rule is to keep people from actively selling (pushing) stuff on the air vs it coming up in a ragchew that they’ve got a car for sale.

Comment: @JonCuster yes, that's definitely the intent, as well as keeping businesses from using it like CB or business band, but the regulations still clearly prohibit any discussion to facilitate a car sale.

Comment: Yes, the fact that a car is for sale may come up in conversation, the actual arrangements should be off the air.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contract law involves a number of parts, the most relevant here being the formation of a contract, and the enforcement of its terms. There are various rules about formation, such as that you cannot hold a gun to a person’s head to force them to say yes (the courts would then say there was no contract), and then under other conditions a term in a contract might be illegal, for instance the courts will not order a person to commit a crime as one of the conditions of a contract.

In the scenario that you propose, no term of the contract involves an illegal action, the only presumed illegality is in the circumstances surrounding formation of the contract. Duress is illegal, because there is no voluntary mutual assent. That’s not the case here. So there is no established legal impediment to finding that a contract was formed. There are ample opportunities to test the theory that an element of illegality in the *formation* of a contract makes the contract void, for example if a physical instrument used in creating or transmitting the contract was used illegally (the paper was stolen, the paper was used without permission of the owner); the assent was made while trespassing; the contract language infringes copyright. Given the court’s very strong commitment to recognizing and enforcing contracts, it is highly unlikely that the courts would reject a contract over a technicality of this type

[§97.113](http://www.arrl.org/files/file/Regulatory/March%208,%202018.pdf) of the FCC rules states the prohibited transmissions, the two relevant clauses being that the prohibited list includes

> (2) Communications for hire or for material compensation, direct or
> indirect, paid or promised, except as otherwise provided in these
> rules;
>
> (3) Communications in which the station licensee or control operator
> has a pecuniary interest, including communications on behalf of an
> employer, with the following exceptions…

(2) is not clearly applicable, since the communication is not for material compensation (e.g. A is not paying B to make a transmission). (3) is more likely applicable, since the parties each have a pecuniary interest in the communication. The exceptions involve being compensated for making a communication, or one can on an irregular basis offer amateur radio apparatus for sale or trade. Since the FCC regulations only provide bare languages and no explanatory texts, and they decline to provide any examples (this seems to be a policy thing), and there is substantial unclarity as to what the restrictions mean, see [this analysis](http://www.arrl.org/files/media/News/ARRL%20appropriate%20use%20guidelines.pdf).

A finding of letter-of-the-law violation in this case cannot be made by the court in which breech of contract would be litigated. Instead, the FCC would have to *first* make a finding of law-breaking, then a party would have to prove in a separate cause of action that because of illegality in the circumstances surrounding formation of the contract, there never was an agreement.

Answer (score -2):

As to being "illegal", (which is a strong word most often associated with criminal activity) if the FCC determined your data burst violated the terms and conditions of your radio station license agreement they might revoke your license, but they have no jurisdiction over car sales.

Now to the question of "binding" or not, there is no automatic voiding of the contract due to the medium used to communicate.  (handshake, verbal, email, etc.)  If they decide to go through with the sale nobody can stop them.

However, if either James or John wanted to get out of the agreement, and the other wanted to enforce it, one could challenge the other.  The plaintiff may choose to make "commercial use" of amateur radio a pillar of their case that the contract is invalid, but it would be up to a judge to decide if the method of transmission of an intent to buy was germane.

Comment: USC 47§97.113 (a) No amateur station shall transmit:... (3) Communications in which the station licensee or control operator has a pecuniary interest, including communications on behalf of an employer, with the following exceptions: [exceptions that don't apply]

Comment: This answer essentially just restates the question. What is the point?

Comment: @bdb484, how so?  There is no question mark in my answer.

Comment: You're saying the answer can only come from a judge. Your unstated premise is that the judge's decision will be based on the law. So the question is whether the law says OP's contract is void, and your answer is that it depends on whether the law says OP's contract is void.

Comment: @bdb484, Do you have the same critique of the final paragraph of user6726’s answer?  Because it essentially says the same thing, and because specific laws can't cover every case, and eventually if it's litigated a Judge will decide.  But if it isn't litigated it is binding, right?

Comment: No. That paragraph is only part of a broader answer that reaches an actual conclusion about whether the contract is binding. However, I do have a different critique of that paragraph -- namely, that it is quite obviously wrong.

Comment: @bdb484 Well, I anxiously await your answer...

Comment: I only answer questions when I've researched and learned the answer. I leave blind guesses to a few of the other users.

Comment: @bdb484, yet you've researched and learned enough to call other people "obviously wrong"...

Comment: I'm only saying that one paragraph is incorrect. The judge hearing the contract case could make an independent determination about the FCC violation if it were necessary to decide the case. I suspect but do not know for certain that the main conclusion of the answer is correct.

Answer (score -4):

> We have violated amateur radio regulations by using it for commercial purposes, but does this nullify the contract?

Most likely it does, since the use you describe hinders at least [one fundamental purpose](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-47/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-97) of an amateur radio service:

> Recognition and enhancement of the value of the amateur service to the
> public as a voluntary noncommercial communication service,
> particularly with respect to providing emergency communications.

The purpose of this contract seemingly fails to outweigh public policy or public interest in enforcing the prohibition.  See [Restatement (Second) of Contracts](http://www.oneclubofjusticides.com/p/restatement-second-contracts.html) at §181.

Furthermore, the existence of legislation in this regard is indicative of the strength of that policy. See *Restatement at §178(3)(b)*. Other criteria listed therein go in the same direction and are self-explanatory.

> Is a contract agreed to in an illegal way binding?

It depends on the specific circumstances, including each party's *mens rea*, during the formation of the contract. The aforementioned sections of the *Restatement* ought to determine the validity.

There are other obvious conditions that render a contract null and void, such as where it is entered under duress or coercion. However, that goes beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: This answer seems to run contrary to general principles of contract law. Citations to relevant law would improve this answer.

Comment: @bdb484 "*This answer seems to run contrary to general principles of contract law.*" You're going to have to explain how *Restatement at §§ 178, 181* depart from the principles of contract law in this context. [*Kiely v. Rayton Co.*, 105 F.3d 734, 736 (1997)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/1997839105f3d7341708) is clear that "*an agreement to achieve mutual benefit from the parties' cooperative violation of the law [...], even if explicitly agreed to by both parties, is void and unenforceable as against public policy*". The radio operators' unawareness of the prohibition seems unlikely.

Comment: Everything you're citing deals with contracts formed to engage in unlawful conduct. None of it addresses contracts negotiated through unlawful conduct, which is what OP is asking about. Imagine giving a phone scammer $10,000 to resolve your tax debts. Can a court void the contract and let him keep your money if it finds you should have known the phone call was illegal because you signed yourself up for the Do Not Call list?

Comment: @bdb484 "*None of it addresses contracts negotiated through unlawful conduct, which is what OP is asking about.*" Operating a ham radio without the requisite license for commercial purposes constitutes unlawful conduct, and *Restatement at §181* addresses that scenario. "*if it finds you should have known the phone call was illegal because you signed yourself up for the Do Not Call list?*" That is a poor analogy and takes things out of the OP's context, in part because your scenario might or might not entail a claim of *unjust enrichment*. But feel free to post your own, separate question.

Comment: I accept that the conduct in question is illegal. The problem is that you're conflating illegality in the *formation* of the contract with illegality in the *performance* of the contract. OP is asking about the former; your answer answer only addresses the latter.

Comment: @bdb484 "*you're conflating illegality in the formation of the contract with illegality in the performance of the contract.*" That distinction is irrelevant. The impairment of critical communications elsewhere is the same regardless of whether the violation was for formation or for performance. Restatement at §178 weighs, *inter alia*, "*the likelihood that a refusal to enforce the term will further that policy*" and whether the violation was deliberate. Unless policy/law is enforced, others will also violate it with under pretext that "*oh, but in this violation I'm only forming a contract*".

Comment: That's a good policy argument, but it's not backed up by any law. Restatement 178 deals only with contract terms, and formation is not a contract term. If such conditions can actually invalidate a contract -- and I suspect that can sometimes be the case -- there's going to be a statute or a decision saying so. I'm just saying your answer would be improved by citing to something more on point.

Comment: @bdb484 "*Restatement 178 deals only with contract terms, and formation is not a contract term.*" Restatement at §178 does not distinguish whether public policy has to be contravened by the terms themselves or by the formation of the contract. "*there's going to be a statute or a decision saying so.*" [*Poller v. OCC*, 960 N.W.2d 496, 521(2021)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/iniaco20210604146) states that "*express statutory language of the unenforceability of an illegally formed contract is not required*", and it denied that "*a contract which is illegally formed may be enforced by OCC*".

Comment: It sounds like maybe you haven't read either the title or first sentence of section 178, both of which are the opposite of what you keep saying. I can see, though, that you are very committed to defending this position, so I won't make any further attempts to disabuse you.

Comment: @bdb484 "*which are the opposite of what you keep saying.*" Not at all. The first sentence mentions "*[when] the interest in its enforcement is clearly outweighed in the circumstances by a public policy*". "*I won't make any further attempts to disabuse you.*" *Poller* should have disabused *you*.  I'm just dismantling your ongoing attempts to mislead the audience: that this goes against principles of contract law, that the answer does not address contracts negotiated through unlawful conduct, that enforcement only looks at performance issues and not at formation issues, and so forth.

Comment: Thanks for your contributions!